# Angular Files Not Loading From Bower

Tags: angularjs

I've installed some AngularJS components via Bower on a Gulp project of mine, but for some reason I can't seem to get them to load alongside my document. This is what I've installed.
    "angular": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-animate": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-cookies": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-resource": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-route": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-touch": "^1.3.0"

This is what my document tree looks like, also:

```
bower_components
Build
 /assets
 /views
 /index.html
```

I'm including the files like so:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
...
```

But for some reason, AngularJS doesn't load onto the page. Is there something I'm missing here? Or is there a better way to go about this?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The bower files need to be added to your servers accepted routes table. Typically they are not accessed relative to the current page like this.

Comment: @Spidy You mean like a gulpfile.js?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, and that is indeed the full list of the dependencies in your bower.json file, then it appears Angular isn't actually installed yet.

Comment: @RyanMiller Sorry, it is there, I just forgot to copy it to my question.

Comment: When you say "doesn't load onto the page", can you confirm you are receiving a 404? Or are you inferring this from something else?

Comment: @RyanMiller The script src isn't pointing to the correct path, if I copy bower_components into the Build folder, my Angular app works. But that seems like a nuisance to have to do.

Comment: Odd - the following arrangement works perfectly for me: https://cldup.com/H7jIW3DcP7.png. If your arrangement is different than that shown in the image, that's likely the cause.

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm using Gulp, and it's throwing my files into that Build folder, that's why it's not referencing the bower folder, because it's outside of the Build folder.

Comment: Why don't you just load it in your index.html page using a CDN? It will load that way.